# Prototype's Ajax.Request not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, prototypejs

I am just doing a simple Ajax.Request call using the newest version of Prototype.  It works fine in Firefox, Internet Explorer, and even Safari... but not in Chrome.  Here is my code...

alert(url);
new Ajax.Request(url, {
  method: 'get',
  onSuccess: function(transport) {
     alert('test');
  }
});

It pops up he URL alert but the test alert never comes up.  Like I said it does in every other browser.  I am not getting any javascript errors and I have used Firebug.  I did a console.log on each event and it gets to the onLoading stage of Ajax.Request but never onLoaded.

Very confused... ?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Prototype? What server are you using (as if that would make any difference)? Also can you post the whole document somewhere?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/CsUgM/2/  Prototype 1.6.1, Chrome 4.1.249.1045 (42898), Windows (XP) SP3. Both alerts show up fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the latest version before I posted this.  So it is 1.6.0.3 or whatever it is.  Not sure why it would make a difference but it is CentOS, Lighttpd, PHP.  It just returns some JSON.

Prototype though never fires the onLoaded event, so seems like it is stalling before it gets sent.  The part that baffles me is no errors in the error log... and it works on Safari.  I'd think since both are Webkit it would be the same in both.

Comment: Can you post the whole document somewhere? Pastebin perhaps? It may be something simple that we will catch but you overlooked.