# Ajax.Request (Prototype v1.6.0.3) not working in Chrome (latest stable Mac version)?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, prototypejs

I'm debugging my JavaScript code that runs well in most browsers so far... but Chrome keeps refusing my Ajax.Request at the moment. Please have a look at the following code:

```
    var base = document.location.pathname.substr(0, document.location.pathname.indexOf('/',1));
    new Ajax.Request(base + '/status.json', {
        method : 'get',
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        onSuccess : function(res) {
            updateProgressBar(res.responseJSON);
        },
        onFailure : function(res) {
            console.error("ProgressBar AJAX failed!");
        },
        onCreate : function(res) {
            console.error("ProgressBar AJAX onCreate!");
        },
        onUninitialized : function(res) {
            console.error("ProgressBar AJAX onUninitialized!");
        },
        onLoading : function(res) {
            console.error("ProgressBar AJAX onLoading!");
        },
        onLoaded : function(res) {
            console.error("ProgressBar AJAX onLoaded!");
        },
        onInteractive : function(res) {
            console.error("ProgressBar AJAX onInteractive!");
        },
        on200 : function(res) {
            console.error("ProgressBar AJAX on200!");
        },
        onComplete : function(res) {
            console.error("ProgressBar AJAX onComplete!");
        }
    });
```

All those onSomethings have been added for debugging... I normally need onSuccess only. But that is never called by Chrome at the moment. It only fires the following events:

```
onCreate
onLoading
```

That's it. No onLoaded or anything else.

Is this a known bug of this version? We use RichFaces v3.3.3.Final which comes with ProtoType. If this simply won't work I'll code my own AJAX Request for Chrome... but I want to make sure that I've not made a simple mistake first. Thanks.

PS: I saw [Prototype's Ajax.Request not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572938/prototypes-ajax-request-not-working-in-chrome) which is rather old... so I started a new topic.

Comment: ...I've tried jQuery.ajax() instead (which comes with RichFaces too) and this works. So I can handle it. But I'm still curious if I made a mistake above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure prototype does not have the `dataType` attribute, try removing that and check again.

Here are the default prototype AJAX options

```
this.options = {
    method:       'post',
    asynchronous: true,
    contentType:  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    encoding:     'UTF-8',
    parameters:   '',
    evalJSON:     true,
    evalJS:       true
};
```

Comment: Maybe I added that option during tests... if it's not used Prototype will sure ignore it. But I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, i know it is not supposed to make a difference since the default properties only get extended, so it's just an extra attribute. I dont have a MAC so i cannot re-create the issue.